# A table with random values from each table

Tags: sql, database

I have 3 table .a,b,c .The Name whose datatype is varchar .I need a query that will get one row from each table and give me a another table namely 'd'.This d will have 3 rows for eg. a1 above b3 above c2 ..these values in table d are random every time I run this query ..

```
Table a   Table b   Table c
 Name      Name       Name
 a1        b1         c1
 a2        b2         c2 
 a3        b3         c3
```

when i run the query I need a table 'd' with random

```
Table d    Table d
 Name       Name
 a2         b1
 b3         a3
 c1         c3
```

and there is no relation between these tables !

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what does your expected resultset look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--TableD

```
select (select top 1 name from @TableA order by newid()) as Name
union all
select (select top 1 name from @TableB order by newid())
union all
select (select top 1 name from @TableC order by newid())
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to select a random record or row from a database table. Here are some example SQL statements that don't require additional application logic, but each database server requires different SQL syntax.

**Select a random row with *MySQL*:**

```
 SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

**Select a random row with *PostgreSQL*:**

```
 SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

**Select a random row with *Microsoft SQL Server*:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 column FROM table
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**Select a random row with *IBM DB2***

```
 SELECT column, RAND() as IDX 
FROM table 
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

**Select a random record with *Oracle*:**

```
 SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column FROM table
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return one random row from each table.

```
WITH  OneRandomRowFromA
    AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                 Name
               , RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6))) AS RandomNumber
         FROM    TableA
         ORDER BY 2
       ) ,
  OneRandomRowFromB
    AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                 Name
               , RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6))) AS RandomNumber
         FROM    TableB
         ORDER BY 2
       ) ,
  OneRandomRowFromC
    AS ( SELECT TOP 1
                 Name
               , RAND(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(6))) AS RandomNumber
         FROM    TableC
         ORDER BY 2
       )
SELECT   Name
FROM     OneRandomRowFromA
UNION ALL
SELECT   Name
FROM     OneRandomRowFromB
UNION ALL
SELECT   Name
FROM     OneRandomRowFromC
```

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it will help you

```
 ---- This will create a random number between 1 and 3           
   DECLARE @Random1 INT;
   DECLARE @Random2 INT;
   DECLARE @Random3 INT;
   DECLARE @Upper INT;
   DECLARE @Lower INT


SET @Lower = 1 ---- The lowest random number
SET @Upper = 4 ---- The highest random number
SELECT @Random1 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)  
SELECT @Random2 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0)       
SELECT @Random3 = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0) 

--query here--
;with tableA AS
(
    SELECT Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber
    FROM a 
),  tableB AS
(
    SELECT Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber
    FROM b 
)
,tableC AS
(
    SELECT Name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Name) AS RowNumber
    FROM c 
)

select Name from tableA where RowNumber= @Random1 
union
 select Name from  tableB where  RowNumber=@Random2  
 union
 select Name from tableC where RowNumber=@Random3
```